# How to split DataFrame using some constraint?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose, I have a DataFrame df. I want to split this DataFrame into new DataFrames such that salaries are always increasing

```
>>> DATA = {'id':[1,2,3,4,5], 'salary':[1200,2300,2400,1200,2100] } 
>>> df = DataFrame(DATA)
>>> df
   id  salary
0   1    1200
1   2    2300
2   3    2400
3   4    1200
4   5    2100
```

From the above DataFrame, I need to get two like below:

```
   DataFrame 1            DataFrame 2
   -----------            -----------
   id  salary   |         id  salary
0   1    1200   |      0   4    1200
1   2    2300   |      1   5    2100
2   3    2400   |
```

Any help?

Comment: This is covered in the documentation, http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html

Comment: @MattiJohn: I don't think it is, at least not there-- I think you're misreading what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: Yes, you're right I misread the question, it's not as straightforward as I thought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like

```
>>> grouped = df.groupby((df.salary.diff() <= 0).cumsum())
>>> parts = [g.reset_index(drop=True) for k, g in grouped]
>>> for p in parts:
...     print(p)
...     
   id  salary
0   1    1200
1   2    2300
2   3    2400
   id  salary
0   4    1200
1   5    2100
```

---

This works because you can take a new group when the difference is <=0:

```
>>> df.salary.diff()
0     NaN
1    1100
2     100
3   -1200
4     900
Name: salary, dtype: float64
>>> df.salary.diff() <= 0
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
Name: salary, dtype: bool
```

Giving us a `True` whenever a new group should begin, and since `True` has a value of 1 as an integer, we can use `cumsum` to give us a new number for each group:

```
>>> (df.salary.diff() <= 0).cumsum()
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    1
4    1
Name: salary, dtype: int32
```